# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:01' for column 'created_at' at row 1

Tags: php, database, laravel

```
Laravel Framework 5.5.43
Server version Mysql    5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

I use Seeder.

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
    *
     * @return void
     */
   public function run()
    {
         $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);


//        factory(App\User::class, 50)->create();

    }
}
```

UserFactory.php

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];


 });


 $factory->defineAs(App\User::class, 'admin',function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
         'name' => 'user',
         'email' => 'user@gmail.com',
         'password' => bcrypt('123456'),
         'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});



$factory->defineAs(App\Article::class, 'admin',function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
        'title' => '_title',
        'slug' => '_slug',
        'description_short' => '_description_short',
    'description' => '_description',
    'meta_title'=>'',
    'meta_description'=>'',
    'meta_keyword'=>'',
    'published'=>'1',
    'viewed'=>2,
];

});
```

UsersTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    //

    factory(App\User::class, 'admin', 1)->create()->each(function ($user){

        $user->user_article()->save(factory(App\Article::class, 'admin')->make());

    });
}
}
```

2018_06_08_112606_create_articles_table.php

```
    public function up()
        {
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->text('description_short')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('image_show')->nullable();
        $table->string('meta_title')->nullable();
        $table->string('meta_description')->nullable();
        $table->string('meta_keyword')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('published');
        $table->integer('viewed')->nullable();
        $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
        $table->integer('modified_by')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

       });
    }
```

2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php

```
 public function up()
        {
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        });
         }
```

I run the command :

```
   php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

And get message:

```
 Seeding: UsersTableSeeder

In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:01' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `slug`, `description_short`, `description`,`meta_title`, `meta_description`, `meta_keyword`, `published`, `viewed`,`created_at`, `updated_at`) values (_title, title-1409181309, _description_short, _description, , , , 1, 2, 1970-01-01 00:00:01, 2018-09-14 13:09:45));      


    In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 **Incorrect datetime value: '1970-01-01 00:00:01' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

I can't understand why I get value 1970-01-01 00:00:01 for column 'created_at'. And how can I correct it?

Furthermore, why I get correct value 2018-09-14 13:09:45 for column 'updated_at'.
Furthermore, after run command above, inserted record to User table.

I think it is strange. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: put this in your seed `'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Comment: Have you accidentally set `$timestamps = false` in your User model, perhaps?

Comment: It may also be because you're doing defineAs twice with the same short-name.

Comment: please post your created_at and updated_at columns' date time format from your database or correct it to what you want

Comment: ceejayoz, i just added foreign_key in User model here:  public function user_article(){


       return $this->hasOne('App\Article','created_at');
        //return $this->hasOne('App\Article');
    } . else I get error , SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'. Maybe in this function covering mistake?

Comment: I have found a mistake. I should change  function user_article(){ return $this->hasOne('App\Article','created_by'); Sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you change `$table->timestamps();` by `$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();`

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. Laravel should already set defaults for `created_at` and `updated_at` if it's an Eloquent model, unless timestamps were switched off in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$factory->defineAs(App\Article::class, 'admin',function (Faker $faker) {

return [
    'title' => '_title',
    'slug' => '_slug',
    'description_short' => '_description_short',
    'description' => '_description',
    'meta_title'=>'',
    'meta_description'=>'',
    'meta_keyword'=>'',
    'published'=>'1',
    'viewed'=>2,
];
```

to this

```
$factory->defineAs(App\Article::class, 'admin',function (Faker $faker) {

return [
    'title' => '_title',
    'slug' => '_slug',
    'description_short' => '_description_short',
    'description' => '_description',
    'meta_title'=>'',
    'meta_description'=>'',
    'meta_keyword'=>'',
    'published'=>'1',
    'viewed'=>2,
    'created_at' => $faker->dateTime(),
    'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime(),
];
```

Same with user factory.

Update

or please check your date time format of columns in database. correct if not matching to what you are sending.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. Laravel should already set defaults for `created_at` and `updated_at` if it's an Eloquent model, unless timestamps were switched off in the model.

Comment: Please note: I'm not OP.

Comment: Your suggest doesn't work. Thanks. I also added 'created_at' => '2018-09-14 13:09:45',
    'updated_at' => '2018-09-14 13:09:45', it also doen't work.

Comment: please post your created_at and updated_at columns' date time format from your database or correct it to what you want

Answer (score 0):

You should set  `protected $dates` in your User model

```
class User extends Model {

    // .. you code

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    // .. you code
```